# How to get Inner Join to show multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

[image: tables]

I am building a search field for the "normas" table. My idea is that when I search for a tag (presión, temperatura, manómetro) the results will display any "normas" associated to these tags (the field IDoriger is the ID from normas table).

Currently reading around online i am using an inner join sentence:

```
SELECT A.Descripcion, B.ID, B.Codigo, B.Nombre FROM Tags A 
INNER JOIN normas B 
ON A.IDOriger = B.ID 
AND A.Descripcion LIKE  '**Whatever i'm searching for**%' 
ORDER BY A.ID DESC
```

This sentence works, but it only displayes one result for some reason. 
For example, if I search for "presión", it will only return row 1 from the normas table, instead of rows 1 and 2).

Any idea why is this? or how to fix it?

Comment: the SQL seems ok. Are you sure some of the 'Presion' tags don't have an accent as in 'Presión'. If that's the case you have to remove the accents from the tag before comparasion.

Comment: what happens when you change condition like this `..A.Descripcion LIKE  '%Whatever i'm searching for%'..`

Comment: Works fine here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed236/5/0

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira or change the collation of the column to an accent-insensitive collation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1917b/1

Comment: @flup: nice... didn't knew that feature.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the info, for some reason adding two "%" as NoDisplayName said worked!!

Comment: ah... well... like 'something%' looks for something at the begging of the word, '%somethig' at the end and '%something%' anywhere in the string. But in you case anyone should do, because you're looking for the whole tag.